# What does this construct mean "__builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)"

Tags: c, gcc, clang, gnu, branch-prediction

Specifically, I am asking about the double '!' in the params of the __built_in.

Is it a double negation, per the 'C' language?

Comment: It can be used to convert any value into a boolean 0 or 1. Ex. `!!(42) == 1`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346929/why-do-we-use-builtin-expect-when-a-straightforward-way-is-to-use-if-else

Comment: `if(x)` and `if (__builtin_expect(!!(x), 1))` should reproduce the same order in generated code. Whoever wrote this is doing premature optimization wrong.

Comment: @Havenard actually, it's an optimization for branch prediction. It's saying that `x` is more than likely non-zero, but it might not be. If it's part of a frequently-checked conditional, the extra performance from successful branch prediction can be substantial.

Comment: Yes but if it is likely to be non-zero, then `if(x)` will suffice. Looking from assembly perspective the only thing this is doing is converting `x` to either 0 or 1 before `test x,x` instead of doing `test x,x` straight on. May be even inducing the compiler to use `cmp x,1` instead, which is worse.

Comment: `if(x)` is a generic test for whether or not `x` is zero. The compiler makes no assumptions as to which value is more likely, thus it must rely on dynamic branch prediction, and may incorrectly guess the first few iterations. However, using `__builtin_expect` will insert a *hint* as to what the initial guess for the branch prediction should be.

Comment: Yes it makes no assumption and just generates the code the order you wrote it, with the block for non-zero first, just like this `__builtin_expect` case would do.

Comment: I'm not saying `__builtin_expect` is useless, I'm just saying it is not fulfilling its purpose in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

The `!!` is simply two `!` operators right next to each other. It's a simple way of converting any non-zero value to `1`, and leaving `0` as-is.  (Aka "booleanize" the value). See [!! c operator, is a two NOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307281/c-operator-is-a-two-not) for more discussion of the logical operator in general, outside the context of `__builtin_expect`.

#### Why we want `!!(x)` for `__builtin_expect`

We want to tell the compiler that `x` is likely to be non-zero, not that `x` is likely to be exactly `1`.  It's the difference between telling the compiler to expect `x != 0` vs. `x == 1`, which might matter for other code in the same function.

We could equivalently have written `__builtin_expect( (x)!=0, 1 )`.

The second arg of `__builtin_expect` is a value the compiler should expect the first expression to be equal to.  This is *not* restricted to booleans; see [How far does GCC's __builtin_expect go?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15468042) for uses of expected values other than 0 or 1.

Comment: Thus, it is superfluous in the example (a boolean context).

Comment: It's necessary for the given `__builtin_expect`, because it takes two values that are expected to be equal. If it was just `if(x)`, then yes, it would be superfluous.

Comment: Say that to the Linux kernel guys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109710/likely-unlikely-macros-in-the-linux-kernel Though it looks like they added that later too...